# How to get last week & last month registered users from db

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I have a table where i have users registration date column I am trying to get last week & last month registered users but don't know how it will work.Here are the other queries which works:

```
$users_today = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date FROM users WHERE DATE(reg_date) = CURDATE()")->fetchColumn();
$users_yesterday = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date FROM users WHERE reg_date=SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)")->fetchColumn();
$users_this_week = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date FROM users WHERE WEEK(reg_date) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE())")->fetchColumn();
$users_month = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date FROM users WHERE MONTH(reg_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())")->fetchColumn();
$users_year = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date FROM users WHERE YEAR(reg_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())")->fetchColumn();
$users_total = $db_con->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users')->fetchColumn();
```

The week starts on Monday.
And Please Let me know are these queries safe to work with (avoid SQL Vulnerability) or any other better suggestions to make these safe.

Comment: Your queries are safe from SQL injection because there are no user variables included in your queries, so there is no way to inject anything.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you define `last week` as being the most recent 7 days before today:

```
$users_last_week = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date 
  FROM users 
  WHERE reg_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)")->fetchColumn();
```

If you define `last week` as being the most recent 7 days which start on Monday and end on Sunday and any of them is before today:

```
$users_last_week = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date 
  FROM users 
  WHERE reg_date BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 + WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY)
  AND SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1+WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY)")->fetchColumn();
```

If you define `last month` as being the most recent 30 days before today:

```
$users_last_month = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date 
  FROM users 
  WHERE reg_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)")->fetchColumn();
```

If you define `last month` as being the calendar month which is before the current month:

```
$users_last_month = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date 
  FROM users 
  WHERE reg_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURRENT_DATE())-1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY)")->fetchColumn();
```

## UPDATE

Regarding remarks for wrong results - removed 1 day from the right bound for LAST WEEK and added 1 day to the left bound for LAST MONTH.

## UPDATE 2

To get the registrations for current week only:

```
$users_this_week = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date 
  FROM users 
  WHERE reg_date BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY)
  AND CURRENT_DATE()")->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. This is working but i have a problem with LAST WEEK COUNT it should count last 7 days not 8 days For example if today is 26 (Thursday) and we are about to count the last week and our first day is monday and last day is sunday then our current week is 23(Monday) - 29(Sunday) then it should count the last week from 16(Monday) - 22(Sunday) but it is counting from 16(Monday) -  23(Monday).

Comment: There is also problem with the LAST MONTH COUNT it should count only from one month not from the other                     for example if current month is 07(july) and last month is 06(june) then it should count from **01 june -  30 june** but it is counting from 05(may) month also, so totally it is counting from **29(may) - 30(june)**.

Comment: Please tell me a bit more about this what is the difference between the following two queries:                                 `$users_last_week = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date 
  FROM users 
  WHERE reg_date BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 + WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY)
  AND SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1+WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY)")->fetchColumn();`   AND                                                                          `$users_last_week = $db_con->query("FROM users WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(reg_date)= (WEEKOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1)")->fetchColumn();
`

Comment: If the current week of the year is 1 - subtracting one from this number will not give you week 52 from the previous year. You will get 0.

Comment: OHHH thats right ! so can you please tell me my following query is good (it works  well )                                                     `$users_this_week = $db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as reg_date FROM users WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(reg_date) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE())")->fetchColumn();`

Comment: WEEKOFYEAR is a synonym for WEEK(date,3) which means the week must have more than 3 days in the given year to be considered part of this year. So you may end up with Dec 30 as Monday counted as week 1 of the next year.

Comment: thanks for that so how can i overcome this issue?how can i get users registered this week?

Comment: Mostly in the same way as for the last week - subtract from current date the day of the week to get the most recent Monday, and then count all registrations >= of this date.

Comment: Can you please show me i am just getting confused while building?